# HTML tags inside Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I want to include a break tag inside the second for loop..How can i do that..can anyone help me in this...I have no idea why this code is not working when i open it in a browser

```
   <html>
<head>
<title>Object oriented Java Script</title>
<script>
var obj={};
function Obj(name,id)
{
this.name=name;
this.id=id;
}
obj["1"]=new Obj('deena','2345');
obj["2"]=new Obj('diana','2346');
obj["3"]=new Obj('dolphin','2347');
</script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
for(var element in obj)
{
for(var prop in obj[element])
{
alert(element+"\n"+prop+"="+star[element][prop]);
}
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where, how, what exactly? You mean like `alert(... + '<br />')`?

Comment: we cannot include html tags on alert!

Comment: Not like that felix...Kind of like using document.write("</br>");..is it possible???

Comment: Sure it's possible, but what's the point in writing only `<br>` tags to the document?

Comment: just a line by line representation..It worked felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to put a newline character, not a break.

```
alert(element+"\n"+prop="="+star[element][prop]);
```

Where `\n` puts a newline between the element and the prop= portion.

Comment: dave can u check the edited code...it is'nt showing an alertbox

Comment: ReferenceError: star is not defined.